# How to generate shadow for rectangle By PDFLIB

Tags: php, pdflib

How to add shadow to a rectangle, which is generated using [PDFLIB](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-gmbh/) in php. I used

```
$p->rect(540,610,44,43);
$p->stroke();
```

to generate rectangles.

Comment: I don't think such function exists. Atleast not according to the [examples](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/shadowed-text/) I have just seen